# how to update the git Credentials for all jobs in jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have 10 Jenkins jobs, these jobs have the same git Credentials to pull the code .

Now I want to update the git credentials for these jobs. How to update the credentials quickly?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Credentials in Jenkins are managed at page: Jenkins -> Credentials -> System -> Global credentials, which looks like:

[image: Global credentials page]

Then you can find your git credential from the list, click the `update` icon at the right-most side to update your existing git credential info. Or you can click `Add Credentials` link at the left-bottom conner, add a new entry and choose it from all Job configuration page.